# Inject Doctrine Repository into controller

Tags: symfony, service, dependency-injection, controller, repository

I had the following controller:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Controller\BaseController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class UserController extends BaseController 
{
    public function allAction(Request $request)
    {
        $users = $this->getDoctrine()
                      ->getRepository('AppBundle:User')
                      ->findAll();

        return $this->respond(['users' => $users], 200);
    } 
}
```

And I would like to inject the repository into the controller (for testing purposes)

**Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Controller\BaseController;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class UserController extends BaseController 
{
    private $userrepository;

    public function __construct(EntityRepository $userrepository)
    {
        $this->userrepository = $userrepository;
    }

    public function allAction(Request $request)
    {
        $users = $this->userrepository->findAll();
        return $this->respond(['users' => $users], 200);
    } 
}
```

**services.yml**

```
services:

    userrepository:
        class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
        factory_service: doctrine.orm.entity_manager
        factory_method: getRepository
        arguments:
            - AppBundle\Entity\User

    usercontroller:
        class: AppBundle\Controller\UserController
        arguments:
            - "@userrepository"
```

**routing.yml**

```
api_users_all:
    path: /api/users.{_format}
    defaults: { _controller: usercontroller:allAction, _format: json }
    requirements:
        _method: GET
```

I keep facing the following error:

**PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php on line 350**

**line 350**

```
return $this->container->get($id);
```

So my guess is that the controller is no longer 'ContainerAware' or something like that.

But I can't seem to figure this out.

I am working with symfony 2.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you configure the router to call controller via service, controller is not created directly but requested from the Dependency Injection container. And yes, there is no longer container because you inject only one parameter to it: user repository.

If you want whole container (which is not recommended) and you extending Symfony Controller in your `BaseController` set it in your service:

```
services:
    usercontroller:
        class: AppBundle\Controller\UserController
        calls: 
            - [setContainer, ["@service_container"]]
        arguments:
            - "@userrepository"
```

If you not extending Symfony Controller, inject container as argument:

```
services:
    usercontroller:
        class: AppBundle\Controller\UserController
        arguments:
            - "@userrepository"
            - "@service_container"
```

Controller:

```
class UserController extends BaseController 
{
private $userrepository;
private $container;

public function __construct(EntityRepository $userrepository, $container)
{
    $this->userrepository = $userrepository;
    $this->container = $container;
}
```

It's not recommended, inject only what you want eg. if you use in your controller only repository and mailer inject only them not the whole container.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, the BaseController I extend is actualy an Extension of the FOSRestController where i made an public method $this->respond() to facilitate the responses I make time and time again. I see you say it is not recommended to inject the whole container. I take it I do something fishy then. What way would be more appropriate then ? As I come from a Laravel Background I am used to bind Concrete classes to Interfaces and inject them this way into a controller

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, but you can make services from that classes and inject them just inject only what you need, or simply don't make controller as service, and if you using repository many times just call your created service `$this->get('userrepository')->findAll()`